# Confused with one step in solving differential equation $y'=ay-b$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

How does the above red circle become the below red circle?
In other words, why we have:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt} \ln \left| y- \frac{b}{a} \right|?$$

Comment: there is an image description

Comment: It really is just a rewriting of the expression using the chain rule

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as 'backwards' logic, we know that
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} \ln |y-b/a|= \dfrac{1}{y-b/a} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dt}= \dfrac{dy/dt}{y-b/a}
$$
So when we see the term on the far right, we can replace it by the term on the far left. The chain rule comes from the fact that $y$ is a function of $t$. So we differentiate $\ln$ 'as normal' but then we need to differentiate the inside with respect to $t$. Let's write the argument of $\ln$ as $R(t)$, i.e. $R(t)= y(t)-b/a$. Then 
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} \ln |y-b/a|= \dfrac{d}{dt} \ln|R(t)|= \dfrac{1}{R(t)} \cdot R'(t)
$$
which makes the Chain Rule simpler to see. But $R(t)= y(t)-b/a$ (or $y-b/a$ if you want to drop emphasize the fact that $y$ depends on $t$) and $R'(t)= y'(t)= \dfrac{dy}{dt}$.

Easier might be separation of variables:
$$
\begin{split}
\dfrac{dy}{dt}&= a \left(y-b/a \right) \\
\dfrac{dy}{y-b/a}7= a \;dt \\
\int \dfrac{dy}{y-b/a}&= \int a \;dt \\
\ln|y-b/a|&= at + C
\end{split}
$$
which we can easily solve for $y$ from there.

Comment: Is that like dy/dt (d/dt (ln|y-b/a|)) = ....    How do I wrtie doing derivative to d/dt ln|y-b/a|

Comment: @cynthiaaaaii I'm not sure what you are asking. The first line circle has the expression on the far right of my $=$'s and the resulting circled line is the far left of my $=$'s. Because they are equal, you can replace one with the other. It's just that normally, we go the other way. For example, we 'normally' go from $\dfrac{4}{4}$ to 1 and not 1 to $\dfrac{4}{4}$. However, the latter can be useful, as is going the other direction in your case.